# EventListener Enter Key

Tags: javascript

Is there an `addEventListener` for the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key?

I have

```
document.querySelector('#txtSearch').addEventListener('click', search_merchants);
```

I know this is intended for `<button>`, but wanted to know if there's an equivalent for catching the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.

Comment: Note that pressing Enter on a button also constitutes a 'click' event.

Answer (score 152, accepted):

Are you trying to submit a form?

Listen to the `submit` event instead.

This will handle `click` and `enter`.

If you must use enter key...

```
document.querySelector('#txtSearch').addEventListener('keypress', function (e) {
    if (e.key === 'Enter') {
      // code for enter
    }
});
```

Comment: As a tip , ````document.addEventListener('keypress', function (e) {}```` . Using directly without ````querySelector```` in case you need more response from any enter strike like login form .

Comment: One important detail *e.which* and *e.keyCode* are currently deprecated the new correct way is *e.key*

**References**

//e.which
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/which

//e.keyCode
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode

//e.key
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key

Comment: The `keypress` event has also been deprecated ([link to MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/keypress_event)) please use the `keydown` event: [link to MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/keydown_event)

Answer (score 26):

Here is a version of the currently accepted answer (from @Trevor) with [key](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key/Key_Values) instead of keyCode:

```
document.querySelector('#txtSearch').addEventListener('keypress', function (e) {
    if (e.key === 'Enter') {
      // code for enter
    }
});
```

Answer (score 11):

You could listen to the `'keydown'` event and then check for an enter key.

Your handler would be like:

```
function (e) {
  if (13 == e.keyCode) {
     ... do whatever ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to use some constant for the key code?

Comment: window.addEventListener("keydown", function (e) {
                if (13 == e.keyCode) {
                 alert('a okooo enter')
                }
            });