# ng-enter with out calling any function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, angular-ngmodel

The below code is a part of a **todo-list** code.

The first line is a *input box* where its value is accessible through **newTodo**.The input box is used to type the new task in the *todo-list.*

```
 <input class="todoField" id="newTodoField" type="text" ng-model="newTodo" placeholder="Add New Todo" ng-enter>
    <button id="todoSubmit" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="addTodo()">Add</button>
```

**There is two way to submit the newly typed task name to js.**

**1**.after typing the task name just by clicking the **add** button(the button is in the second line) of the code.which is calling `addTodo()` js function which does the job of adding the typed text in the todo-list.

**2**.after typing the task name just pressing enter button with in the input box.

> the doubt is with the second type method.Because the ng-enter does't
>   call any function. It was just simply written in the end of tag.( If
>   the code was like `ng-enter="addTodo()"` means i would have clearly
>   understood)
>
> And more over even if the ng-enter does't call any function the second
>   method works nicely.How the `ng-enter` model supposed to call the
>   `addTodo()` function.

The complete code is available in [this_link](http://blog.jaykanakiya.com/angular-js-todo-list-sortable/).
The demo of the complete program is available in [this_link](http://jaykanakiya.com/demos/angular-js-todolist/)

sorry if the question is very basic.

Comment: Perhaps [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17470790/how-to-use-a-keypress-event-in-angularjs) answers your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*the doubt is with the second type method.Because the ng-enter does't call any function. It was just simply written in the end of tag.( If the code was like `ng-enter="addTodo()"` means i would have clearly understood)*

Frankly speaking there is no documentation about `ng-enter` at angular docs but you can make it work with using a directive `ngEnter` like:

```
app.directive('ngEnter', function() {
    return function(scope, element, attrs) {
        element.bind("keydown", function(ev) {
            if(ev.which === 13) {
                scope.addTodo();
                ev.preventDefault();
            }
        });
    };
});
```

Comment: @sivashanmugamkannan glad to help you and you are welcome

Answer (score 0):

Cant you add a listener on the textbox? As shown in this link: [EventListener Enter Key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14542062/eventlistener-enter-key)

You could get something like this:

```
$(function(){
  document.querySelector('#newTodoField').addEventListener('keypress',function(e){
  var key = e.which || e.keyCode;
  if (key === 13) { // 13 is enter
   addTodo();
  }
 });
});
```