# How to make the same event attached to button click to trigger while pressing enter key?

Tags: javascript, html, addeventlistener, enter

How can I make the same `EventListener` to trigger when pressing enter key as well on a keyboard?

```
<form>
  <input type="text" class="form"/>
  <button type="button" id="button" class="form">Go!</button>
</form>

let btn = document.getElementById("button");
btn.addEventListener("click", runEvent);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [EventListener Enter Key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14542062/eventlistener-enter-key)

Answer (score 2):

Listen for the [`keydown`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/keydown_event) event on the `document` (or `form`) and then in that event handler, [check for the `"Enter"` key](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key) being pressed. If so, call the `click` event handler:

```js
let btn = document.getElementById("button");
btn.addEventListener("click", runEvent);

document.addEventListener("keydown", function(event){
  if(event.key === "Enter"){
    runEvent();
  }
});

function runEvent(event){
  console.log("Running!");
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" class="form"/>
  <button type="button" id="button" class="form">Go!</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
btn.addEventListener("keydown", function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 13) {  //This checks whether the enter key is pressed or not      
       //Your code.
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the Keydown event listener

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
    if (e.key === 'Enter') {
      runEvent();
    }
});
```

Comment: `keypress` is deprecated. Also, if a `button` has the focus, which your code would require, then pressing ENTER would cause the `click` event to trigger.

Comment: @ScottMarcus Oh yeah, d'oh. Wrote quickly. Edited to reflect the fact

Comment: Your main answer still says `keypress`.